# How to reset ISA13 (Interchange control number) in BizTalk 2006

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

I am facing a problem in BizTalk 2006. The problem is that I have to reset ISA13 (Interchange control number).

Comment: Are you using BizTalk 2006 R2 or BizTalk 2006 with Covast?

Comment: I am using BizTalk 2006 without covast.

Comment: I assume this is 2006 R2 then. As far as I know, EDI/X12 support was not implemented in 2006 "R1".

Comment: No its BT 2006 not R2. I am very much sure.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, I had no idea there was EDI support in 2006.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I only have a BizTalk 2010 available here, so i'm not sure if this functionality is already present in BizTalk 2006/2006 R2.

In BizTalk 2010 and 2009 you have the option to reset the ISA on the following party agreement (see image below).

Do you have a similar option in BizTalk 2006 R2 in the party settings?

[image: Agreement properties]

Comment: Thanks Pieter for your answer. But I don't think this functionality is available in BT 2006. That's why I am trying to find any possible workaround, if so. Also I am using BT 2006 not BT 2006 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not have BizTalk 2006/R2 installed. 
My suggestion is looking for the related stored procedure, which in my BizTalk 2013 installation, it looks like the edi_ResetX12Icn in BizTalkMsgBoxDb.